# How apps installed at pip really works?

Tags: django, pip, django-apps

I'm new at django and i was looking for a wysiwyg and i fuond tinymce.
I installed at pip command line and i expect that create a folder at my folder project like a new app. It dont created no one folder but i did the next steps and for my surprise the app works fine at my project.
I want to know how this app really works at my project, in case im gonne deploy this project and how to deploy the app installed at pip or something like that.
My englhish is not good but i hope that was clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The applications, or libraries rather are copied directly inside one of the folders inside your python directory called `Lib/site-packages`. This exact location depends on your operating system you can find usually find your newly installed packages under

**For Windows**

```
C:/PythonXX/Lib/site-packages/
```

**For Linux**

```
/usr/local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages
```

When you run a python script, `Python` will automatically include these folders as available resources, and when you add for example `import X` to your code, it will check to see if `X` is listed.

You have more information on the topic available [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html).

Comment: i'm at windows so tinymce is on c:/python/lib/site-packages, thanks that was clear to me, so.. when i was deploy my code i need upload this packages too? do you know some acticle that can explain that part better?

Comment: I'll see if I can find one, but you could simply copy these folders to your project folder as well, but it is recommended to keep them there, to make upgrading packages etc easier, and also to make sure that other projects can use them as resources.